# jQuery ScrollPane not displaying scroll bar for p tag

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm learning jQuery right now and going through a book's lessons.  I'm implementing the `jScrollPane.js` and `jquery.mousehweel.js` plugins.  I'm trying to apply a custom scrollbar to a paragraph.  However, nothing is showing up.  I'm not sure why.  Here's my markup:

```
 <h2>
            Fine Print</h2>
        <p id="fine_print">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
            incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud
            exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute
            irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla
            pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia
            deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
```

Here's my script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fine_print").jScrollPane({
            scrollbarWidth: 10,
            scrollbarMargin: 10,
            showArrows: false
        });
    });
```

Here are my links to the stylesheets/js files.

```
 <head>
<title>Hello jQuery World!</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<!-- styles needed by jScrollPane -->
<link type="text/css" href="jScrollPane.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- the jScrollPane script -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jScrollPane.js"></script>
<!-- the mousewheel plugin - optional to provide mousewheel support -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>-->
```

Here's the css I got from the book:

```
 #fine_print 
 {
 height:50px;
 overflow:auto;
 margin:0;
 }
```

I'm not sure if anything else is needed.  I thought I would provide what I thought was required with filling the entire page with a book of code.  If anything else is needed, I'll provide it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can directly apply jScrollPane on a `<p>` element.

The plugin expects more that you have the following structure:

```
<div id="use_jScrollPanel_on_this">
   <p>
      ...
   </p>
</div>
```

In terms, a container wrapping the element(s) to be scrollable.

A quick view of the plugin code shows this line:

```
pane = $('<div class="jspPane" />')
              .css('padding', originalPadding).append(elem.children());
```

It creates a DIV and appends the content of "elem" into it. Now "elem" is the element you called .jScrollPane() onto. If you call it directly on a `<p>` element, nothing is appended in the created DIV as the paragraph has no children (.children() does not retrieve text nodes).

Here are two fiddles that shows your not working and the working solution (with a container wrapping the paragraph):

- [Applied on `<p>`](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/FmCrA/) (not working)
- [With `<p>` wrapped in a DIV](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/W8MQE/) (working)

---

Also make sure the CSS file is correctly referenced otherwise the whole jscrollpane won't work as it will not display the nested containers it creates correctly.

Comment: I went that route in my markup because I was able to find their source code and saw that they too apply the id directly to the `<p>` tag.

Comment: Well, the wrapping element does not have to be a `<div>`, it can be a `<p>` element - but there must be a container. I think the fact that the elements should be wrapped is motivated by progressive enhancement: if javascript is disabled, thanks to the `overflow: auto` on the wrapper, the elements will be scrollable with native scrollbars